# App works on iPad 3, but has issues on iPad 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

I have an App that I am working on that works flawlessly on iPad 3, but when I load it on iPad 2, Core data seems to not be saving properly and my data is not loading. I have checked memory usage and I never exceed 55MB in worst-case scenario.

I am looking for any gotchas, or weird quirks that may be causing this behaviour that is device specific, they are all on the same iOS version.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I'm thinking its going to either be CoreData or NSOperationQueue that are the culprits as I use both.

Also this only appears to be failing in Release config, when I run through xcode the app is fine on iPad 2 as well so that cuts my debugging abilities by quite a bit.

Comment: Does it fail only when updating?

Comment: Are both devices running the same iOS version?

Comment: Does your app create a MemoryWarning?

Comment: Make sure that your CoreData model is the same on both devices.  If you make changes and the old model is available it will often crash your app.  You can delete the app to redo the model or do an immigration at run time.

Comment: its a brand new app, and fresh install. no memory warnings and removal and reinstall doesn't help. both devices (actually 4 devices so far 2 iPad 2's and 2 iPad 3's) are on the same iOS

Comment: @Undo it doesn't crash or anything, my data just doesn't show up. I guess I can grab the sqlite file to see if the data is being saved properly.